# Performance drop when embedding youtube videos + reverse engineering a site that does it right

Tags: javascript, html, performance, youtube, reverse-engineering

When embedding youtube videos in a HTML + vanilla JS page we get a huge performance drop as all the videos are preloaded.  (videoplayback?expire=..... requests)

I discovered that vodafone's job landing page have two videos, and they lazy load them. I really love the result:

- You can interact directly with the video (share for later button for example)
- 0 request during loading time
- Videos play smoothly when clicked

You can check it here: https://careers.vodafone.com/

I saw a lot of ways to lazy load with css, plugins... but I saw nowhere a solution as clean as the one from vodafone.

No sign at all of the videos on page load:
[image: vodafone's jobs page]

Anyone understands how they did it? It's a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Vodafone doesn't do anything special here, just a regular `iframe` pointing to the embed page.

```html
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9cC0CZiVpsA?rel=0&amp;autoplay=0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

The first request to YouTube happens before the `DOMContentLoaded` event (blue bar in the image) and way before the page is fully loaded (red bar). The preview images are loaded between the two bars.

[image: First request to YouTube]
[image: Preview image loaded]

Requests to `videoplayback` however should only start once you click on one of the videos. Could it be that you added `;autoplay=1` to the video url or an `autoplay` attribute to the `iframe`?

Comment: You're right. Is just an iframe. Not even with the loading="lazy" attribute and it works nice...
I'm trying to fix it in an old jquery page and it's consuming my brain!